# Facing issue while appending dropdown object with string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to append dropdownlist in div with ul li. When I am append with whole ul li string then it is appearing like [object object] where as if I append only dropdown then it is coming as html dropdown control that is correct.
Is there any way to append dropdown with string?

**My Html:**

```
<select id='sel'>
  <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
  <option value='4'>Option 4</option> 
</select>
<a id="aselect" onclick="createNewSelect('#sel');">Add</a>
```

**My jquery function:**

```
 function createNewSelect(a) {    
    var selVal = $(''+ a +'').val();
    var ddl = $(''+ a +'').clone();
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(ddl).find("option[value='"+ selVal +"']").remove();            
    });
    var newId = 'sel' + $('select').length;
    $(ddl).attr('id',newId);            
    $('#aselect').attr("onclick","createNewSelect('#"+ newId +"')");

    $("body").append("<li class=\"span3 no-margin\"><span>Social Media</span><br>" + ddl + "</li>");
    $("body").append(ddl);       
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4uqgmqzc/3/

Comment: What is the output you're trying to create?

Comment: Upper code is just sample. I have do append dropdown with whole ul li and other input. So it will look like "dropdown Textbox  addbutton". So when I click on addbutton it will generate again "dropdown Textbox".

Comment: try ddl[0].outerHtml, check my answer

Comment: Dnt know why people giving minus. What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to append whole object instead of html you need to update your code as shown below

```
function createNewSelect(a) {    
        var selVal = $(''+ a +'').val();
        var ddl = $(''+ a +'').clone();
        $('select').each(function() {
            $(ddl).find("option[value='"+ selVal +"']").remove();            
        });
        var newId = 'sel' + $('select').length;
        $(ddl).attr('id',newId);            
        $('#aselect').attr("onclick","createNewSelect('#"+ newId +"')");

        $("body").append("<li class=\"span3 no-margin\"><span>Social Media</span><br>" + ddl[0].outerHTML + "</li>");

        $(ddl).change(function() {
            createNewSelect(this);
        });  
}
```

good luck !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your snippet to simple callback. Your snippet would be

```
<select id='sel'>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Option 4</option> 
</select>
<a id="aselect" onclick="createNewSelect2('#sel');">Add</a>
<ul id="out"></ul>
```

And your javascript code would be

```
function createNewSelect2 () {
    $("#out").append("<li>" + $("select#sel :selected").text() + "</li>");
    $("select#sel :selected").remove();
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beera/4uqgmqzc/7/)

Answer (score -1):

try to append it like this `$("body").append(ddl[0]);`

What you are trying to append is a jquery object. Basically an array of all the select elements which in your case is just one. hence use the index accessor to get the select statement and append.